# How to import npm package to meteor with hyphen/dash in the name

Tags: meteor, npm, import

I installed bootstrap-colorpicker npm package and I'm trying to import to my meteor app.

I did read "Using npm packages" and I tried to use their example: "import moment from 'moment';". but the problem is the there is a hyphen/dash in the middle of the name and it throws an error.
where should I look in the package to know how to import a npm package?

here is what i did:

```
import bootstrap-colorpicker from 'bootstrap-colorpicker';

Template.Test.onRendered(function() {
$('#m-color-picker').colorpicker();
});
```

I want the #m-color-picker to turn into a color picker, but it gives me error for the hyphen/dash.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any name you like for the module in your code, eg

```
import bootstrapColorpicker from 'bootstrap-colorpicker';
```

or

```
import colorpicker from 'bootstrap-colorpicker';
```

Easy as that

For the second part of your question:

Usually the 'getting started' part of the README file should tell you how to import a module, although some older packages only mention how to require a package, which I presume is where you are coming from.

Quite often the default export will be what you need, so for example, referring to the momentjs web site:

> var moment = require('moment');

You can usually assume this:

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

Basically this is taking the top level object from the module.

Comment: Okay I'm embarrassed now. But the second part of my question "where should I look in the package to know how to import a npm package". 
Right now when I `console.log(colorpicker)`, it looks like it did not import it, even my `('#m-color-picker').colorpicker()` gives me this error: _TypeError: $(...).colorpicker is not a function_

Answer (score 0):

Your specific package doesn't seem to export anything, but just has some side-effects (perhaps it monkey-patches itself into jQuery?), so you can even drop the first part of the import and just say:

```js
import 'bootstrap-colorpicker';
```